# OS X some files on SMB share are grayed out

Tags: macos, smb

On my Mac with OS X 10.6 I can mount and work on a SMB share without any problems. But some times some files on this share are grayed out. If I double click on them nothing happens. If pull a grayed PDF file to Preview it opens without problems.

I suspect, that an OS X process is locking this files. How can I find the guilty process an stop it?